# SU Retag Request: [cmd] --> [command-line]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

All questions tagged [cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd) are also tagged [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) or something similar,
given that there is already a more popular tag [command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line) shouldn't we just retag all questions?

[cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd) might be made **a synonym** for ease of access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged [cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd) into [command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line) and created the synonym.